# Can I open an existing Visual Studio Project (C++) on MAC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using [this C++ book](https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-c-programming-382-detail) for a college class. I have a MAC and have installed Visual Studio (Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.3.11 (build 1)) and am trying to open the code examples supplied with the book. The book includes examples for Visual Studio as well as xcode. I am able to open the xcode projects, however when I try and open the VS examples (.sln file) I get the error message "This project type not supported..." (see image below). Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what the project does. If it's a project specifically designed for Windows, then you can't open it on a Mac. If the project is Windows only, you can fix it by using a Windows computer with VS installed to open it.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I think that answers my question. I am teaching a class and many of the students are going to be using VS so I wanted to work alongside them using the same IDE. Looks like I'll just stick with Xcode.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 for Mac support these languages: C#, F#, Razor, HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, TypeScript, XAML, and XML.  Doesn't support C++.

Comment: Duh! Good call @Eljay. All else fails read the documentation right?  

Comment: Entirely understandable misunderstanding.  Visual Studio as a Microsoft brand is strongly associated with C++.  Overused branding, in my opinion, when one considers Visual Studio Online and Visual Studio Code and (in this case) Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio for MAC does NOT support C++.